# How to get MediaPlayer_complete event in outlook custom form?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

i'm using following code in custom form:

```
Dim MediaPlayer
Set oMediaPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
oMediaPlayer.settings.volume = 100
MediaPlayer.controls.stop()
MediaPlayer.settings.autoStart = false
MediaPlayer.URL = strWavFile
MediaPlayer.controls.play()
```

I would like to know when will be the end of music, like that:

```
Sub Play_Complete()
    MsgBox "Song successfully played"
End Sub
```

I'm not sure, exist this event in vba-outlook.

I also tried to do time event but when I googled, I did not find anything worthwhile that can apply to my situation. Most of examples didn't work in vba-outlook

Rgds,
Dmitry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare the following sub:

```
Sub oMediaPlayer_Complete()
  MsgBox "Song successfully played"
End Sub
```

where the word after the underscore symbol is the event name.

Anyway, Outlook custom forms is a relatively old technology. Instead, I'd suggest developing an add with an Outlook form region. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: To my misfortune, this event doesn't fire.

Comment: Then I'd recommend developing an Outlook form region instead.